# Run Sub in main window from second window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I'll try to explain as best I can. I have a Sub in my main window that pulls data from SQL and loads it into a datagrid.

I have a second window that is opened via button click. When the second window closes I want the Sub for the datagrid to run.

I have tried to reference the datagrid Sub after I say Me.Close() but I get "Reference to a non-shared member required an object reference."

I cannot share the sub because I then get the error "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method..."

I have also tried a Window_Closed event handler this also gives me "Reference to a non-shared member required an object reference." when I reference the datagrid

Anyone any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a EventHandler in your MainWindow for the FormClosing event of your second Window or show your second form using the ShowDialog Method and run your method after the Form Closes. Something like this should work.

**First Method**

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim secondWindow As New Window1
    AddHandler secondWindow.Closing, AddressOf SecondWindowClosing
    secondWindow.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub SecondWindowClosing(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
    'Run your data method here
End Sub
```

**Second Method**

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim secondWindow As New Window1
    secondWindow.ShowDialog()
    'Run your data method here

End Sub
```

Comment: @user3470664 Glad to be of help